# Dictionary error - TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I'm trying to store some data as dictionary/JSON in JS in React-Native.

I have defined the dictionary like this :

```
  const [item, setItem] = useState({});
```

```
function onUpdate(id, quantity) {
    console.debug('tab index : ' + tabIndex);
    console.debug('id : ' + id);
    console.debug('quantity : ' + quantity);
    console.debug(item);
    item[tabIndex][id] = quantity;
    console.debug(item);
    //I'm not setting it
    //I have even tried declaring a second object, like :
    //let i=item
    //It also causes the same problem
  }
```

In log I'm getting :

```
[Tue Aug 11 2020 13:19:13.195]  DEBUG    tab index : 1
[Tue Aug 11 2020 13:19:13.198]  DEBUG    id : 1
[Tue Aug 11 2020 13:19:13.202]  DEBUG    quantity : 1
[Tue Aug 11 2020 13:19:13.203]  DEBUG    {}
[Tue Aug 11 2020 13:19:13.204]  ERROR    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item[tabIndex][id] = quantity')
```

Why is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason wise , as mentioned by @Amaden ,
since the item[tabIndex] is undefined , hence when you are trying to add something in that undefined you are getting the error.

So you should first check for the undefined condition , if it is undefined create object first and then add , else you can directly add the data .

```js
var item = {};
var tabIndex = 1;
var id = 1;;

if(item[tabIndex] === undefined){

  item[tabIndex] = {};
  item[tabIndex][id]=10;
} else {

  item[tabIndex][id] = 12;
}

console.log(item);
```

Answer (score 3):

If `item` is `{}`, then `item[tabIndex]` is `undefined`; then `item[tabIndex][id]` is equivalent to `undefined[id]`, which causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

The `item` object is empty `{}` this is why you are getting undefined, please check the area where you are setting up the data in `items`.
first check for the undefined condition , if it is undefined create object first and then add.

```
if(item[tabIndex] === undefined){
    // create object first
} else {
   // directly add the data
}
```